# Is it possible to know the host device where an HTML5 app was launched?

Tags: android, ios, html, hardware, web-audio-api

I would like to know if my app was launched in an iPod Touch 5g, a Samsung S3 mini, or an iPad 4, is it possible?
What I have tried it with navigator.userAgent but I can only detect if it's an iPod or iPad, but not its specific version (5th gen for example)...
I would like to know that because I am generating audio signals and, as every device have its own codec/amplifier circuitry, I could fix deviations in code.
I would like to know if I am generating the same dB level for each device as it is mandatory for my app...

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about event based analytics tool for your app. I generally use Flurry SDK for that, but since your question is for HTML5 app, you can use Bango SDK or Google Analytics, although I am not sure both supports event based analytics or not.